# JSF datatable can not get the exact object after sortBy

Tags: jsf, datatable, tablesorter

I created a JSF table like this:

```
<c:dataTable value="#{myViewController.all}" id="myViewTable" var="T" selection="#{myOtherView.select}" selectionMode="single" update="otherView> 
<c:column filterBy="#{T.name}" sortBy="#{T.name}"> 
    <f:facet name="header"> 
        <h:outputText value="Name"/> 
    </f:facet> <h:outputText value="#{T.name}"/> 
</c:column>
```

Suppose that I have two entries within this table, they are name = a, and name = b. The method in myOtherView.select is

```
@SelectEvent 
public void setSelect(Object value) {

}
```

I debuged the value in setSelect method. When open the view first time, I selected the first row from the table and the value is indeed a. Then I presses the header of 'Name', and the entries showing in the table is b then a. And I selected the first row from the table, the value is still a. not b..... Anyone who knows why this happened?**

Comment: How is `c:` prefix declared? Standarized prefix for jsf components is `h:`.

Comment: c is actually my own tag, created for h:dataTable, I added some styles for it